# Show loading icon until table has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, loading

I have some `javascript/jQuery` that loads a table on the click of a search button and does not do a page load. Usually when I want to show a loading icon, I would dismiss it once the page has loaded... But there is no page load on this. The user could be on the page for 5 minutes before they search and when they click the search button, the loading icon would appear and once the table has loaded their results, it would dismiss...

Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this?

Comment: most likely you are doing ajax call to get the data from server, so show a loading section before making the ajax call and once data has been loaded in your table hide that section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place a Loading text/image in a `div`.

```
<div id="loading" style="display: none;">Loading..</div>
```

Control the appearance of above `div` With `jQuery` `ajaxStart` & `ajaxStop` methods.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
  $("#loading").show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
  $("#loading").hide();
});
```

The above method triggers whenever there is an active `AJAX` call.